# Windows Phone 8 device as a Proximity Access Card

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

Can the NFC hardware within Lumia 920 emulate a 125 kHz Proximity Access Card?

It looks like the NFC hardware implements the standard that is a superset of the standard that access cards use. But I don't have enough knowledge of those radio standards to understand if a phone can work only as a receiver or also as a transmitter of such signals.

I will also appreciate a link to a good overview article that explains those standards in simpler terms than the official specifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, card emulation is **not** supported by the Windows Phone [proximity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Sources:

- [NFC, card emulation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/e6f5ee46-cdd1-4a9d-b13d-81b1adef854f)
- [NFC Developer Comparison](http://www.nfcinteractor.com/developers/nfc-developer-comparison/)

Comment: +1 on the accuracy of this answer. If you want to see this feature in future releases please suggest it on http://wpdev.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @JustinAngel - I really like your blog, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the feature request http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/3511832-access-cards-api

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible from the physics perspective and standards. NFC is based upon ISO 14443 and is using 13,56 MHz wave carrier - which is high-frequency layer - it is typically the electric field scope.
125 kHz is the proximity scope (125 kHz - 134 kHz) which uses magnetic induction (and magnetic field) as the communication environment.
Conclusion - it is physically impossible in this exact case. You could if you would use 13,56-solutions as proximity (this is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
This white paper details the features in Windows Phone 8.1 that you can use to create a UICC-based NFC card-emulation app.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43681