# Windows Phone card emulation mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc

Can anyone give me some guidelines on how to use the CardEmulationMode in a Windows Phone 8? I am a beginner in windows phone programming and I require my phone to be used in NFC Card Emulation Mode for an app I am creating.

Comment: find examples in MSDN . Once you encounter problem on programming, ask here.

Comment: I am not finding any examples that is the problem. The only thing I find is the method public static CardEmulationMode CardEmulationMode { get; } but I am unsure how to use it

Comment: Good question. You'd think there'd be information in MSDN, but I wasn't able to find anything relevant to writing a new app that uses NFC to emulate a card.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14128879/151791) suggests that card emulation mode isn't currently supported by the Windows Phone [proximity API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207060%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Sorry.

Comment: I checked, and found an answer on another question that indicates this isn't currently possible. I'm putting the answer here to make it easier to find next time.